# Firebase simple login for authentication with the REST api

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

I want to create a web app with AngularJS and Firebase but only some parts of the app need the 3-way binding Firebase offers. The other parts would work just finding binding only once to the current data without constantly updating it. In other words, a normal REST API would suffice.

The [Thinkster AngularJS-Firebase tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/learn-to-build-realtime-webapps/) shows how to use `$resource` to access this Firebase REST API. This approach does not require to open a concurrent connection to your Firebase and only fetches the current data without updating:

```
app.factory('Post', function ($resource) {

return $resource('https://FIREBASE-URL.firebaseIO.com/posts/:id.json');
});
```

Would it be possible to do these kind of requests after logging in to Firebase using the simple login service, but **without** keeping a Firebase connection open. For example:

```
//Does this already open a connection to FireBase?
var ref = new Firebase('https://FIREBASE-URL.firebaseIO.com');

//Login to FireBase
ref.authWithPassword({
  email    : "bobtony@firebase.com",
  password : "correcthorsebatterystaple"
}, function(error, authData) {
  if (error === null) {
    // Can we close the connection now while still leaving the user authenticated?
    Firebase.goOffline();
  } else {
    console.log("Error authenticating user:", error);
  }
});
```

If I would make requests to the REST API now:

1. Will Firebase recognize the `auth` variable?
2. Does the authorization stay valid?
3. Can I use this method to prevent the connection to stay open and use Firebase as a normal REST API?

To make things a little bit more clear:

- I do not need a real-time backend, a simple REST backend will suffice
- I would like to use Firebase because it provides easy authentication methods
- If possible, I want to avoid using the Firebase SDK and only interact with my Firebase using the REST API

In other words my question would be:

Is it possible to authenticate users client side to use the security rules of Firebase while using Firebase as a REST API without using the SDK?

Comment: There's no advantage to using the REST API and SDK in tandem. If you already have the SDK downloaded and have already established a socket connection, it's going to be more efficient, cheaper, and less complex to re-use the existing connection. The SDK is also heavily optimized over the REST API and much better at dealing with temporary disconnections and networking errors. By utilizing the REST API, you'll essentially be making your life more difficult for zero gain.

Comment: Try to simplify your question to one use case that you want to resolve. You've essentially asked a dozen questions and not provided the use case you are trying to resolve. Presumably your goal is to optimize, but what we are optimizing is unclear, which is why you haven't received more answers here. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of extremely premature optimization, and it's also detrimental more than helpful.

There's no advantage to using the REST API and SDK in tandem. If you already have the SDK downloaded and have already established a socket connection, it's going to be more efficient, cheaper, and less complex to re-use the existing connection. The SDK is also heavily optimized over the REST API and much better at dealing with temporary disconnections and networking errors. By utilizing the REST API, you'll essentially be making your life more difficult for zero gain.

If your goal is to download data exactly once without listening for updates, simply use [once](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html) in place of on.

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://FIREBASE-URL.firebaseIO.com');
  ref.once('value', function(snap) {
     $scope.data = snap.val();
     $scope.apply();
  });
});
```

Creating a ref() does not immediately create a connection. The first time you authenticate, write, or read data, the connection is established.

Authenticating via the SDK does not help at all for REST queries. You need to pass `?auth=TOKEN` into the URL, where TOKEN is an auth token that you create manually (not at all connected to the SDK simple login auth event).

If you don't want real-time capabilities, don't use the SDK at all. Simply utilize $http or $resource and connect via the .json URLs.

Comment: You are right when you are saying I'm not looking for real-time data and I was wondering if it is possible to avoid opening a Firebase connection while still being able to use the Firebase simplelogin methods. 

This would essentially mean using Firebase as a REST-backend without the 3-way binding. Are you saying I shouldn't try to use Firebase this way? Or is it possible but just not in the way I showed? 

I was asking if it is possible to use Firebase as a REST-backend while still using the simplelogin methods to avoid writing my own authentication server.

Comment: I hope this clarifies some things, thank you for your response!

Comment: It's not possible to use simple login in conjunction with the REST API. I also don't see any gains in utilizing the REST API if you have an SDK available. It's faster, cheaper, and way more fun to program (read simpler).

Comment: I'd just like to point out that you're very quick to write off using the REST API. You're correct in pointing out that it's faster - a pipe is open to the server so no additional handshaking is required. However firebase charges based on concurrent connections, so unless i'm missing something it is most definitely not cheaper in any way to use the SDK.

Comment: Cheaper as in efficiency, not as in dollars. Also, most developers vastly overestimate concurrent connections and the cost. For example, an app with around 10k concurrent connections is probably running around 14 *million* monthly visits, which is more than enough to pony up some cash for a complete back end solution featuring lightning-fast, scalable, realtime capabilities, free hosting with SSL, and dead simple auth. So yeah, in general, using the REST API to turn all of that into a CRUD app, for the sake of getting around the concurrents limit is probably a waste of time and money.